# iPhone: Layering a transparent openGL view on top of a UIView?

Tags: iphone, opengl, uiview, transparency

I am working on iPhone app and I have an openGL view rendering on top of a regular UIView.  It's working, but I can't seem to get the openGL view to have a transparent background that shows the UIView underneath.  Instead, I get a big black box.

I have tried setting the background color to UIColor clearColor, I've set opaque to NO, I've set glClearColor to 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0.

I think I'm misunderstanding/misusing something related to blend modes, but I'm not sure.  Can anyone give me a bit of sample code which shows how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am having similar problem. I am using kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8 in drawableProperties.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's what I had to do to get this to work:

```
eaglLayer.opaque = NO;      
eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

And incase you're doing what I was doing and are trying to test it with the GLGravity demo, there's another call to `glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);` every time `drawView` is called -- so make sure you change that one to `glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);` too!  :)

Comment: I found the "drawableProperties" was unnecessary in iOS 5 and above

Comment: HOWEVER ... I want to point out that you MUST call "opaque = NO" in "viewDidLoad" or similar - if you set it in the NIB file, Apple silently overwrites it at runtime (evil!)

Answer (score 4):

Add those in EAGLView.m

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder

self.opaque = NO;
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;
eaglLayer.opaque = NO;

CGColorSpaceRef rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
const CGFloat myColor[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
eaglLayer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreate(rgb, myColor);
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgb);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the color format of your view. If you’ve set it to `kEAGLColorFormatRGB565` via the `drawableProperties` dictionary, the alpha channel of the view’s contents will be implicitly treated as 1.0, regardless of what you draw into it.