# too much overhead for drawing polygons on uiview

Tags: ios, uiview, drawing, polygon, drawrect

im trying to create a overlay view using a ui view and need to draw about 2000 polygons onto the view. but the performance is really slow and everytime it redraws it will take a long time. currently im drawing these polygons by pointing points onto the uiview and then linking the points together with lines.

is there some standard way to do this that would reduce overhead?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- Try using OpenGL ES to render your polygons.
- Use the profiler (Instruments) to figure out how your code is spending its time, and change your code to spend less doing it.

If you want more help from stack overflow, you need to run the profiler, and edit your question to show the profiler results and your drawing code.

If you don't know how to use Instruments, go to http://developer.apple.com/videos/ios/ and watch the video "Optimizing App Performance with Instruments".

Comment: thank you, do you know if its possible to use openglES to draw on top of a UIVIEW in a normal application? i've never done so before so would just like to know. cheers.

Comment: Re: using less time in your drawing code, are you only redrawing the dirty region of the view or are you redrawing everything? If most of the view doesn't change in a redraw, you waste a lot of time of you draw the whole thing.

Comment: The thing is the view is a overlay for a bingmaps view, so when the bingmap resizes (via zoom or scroll), the overlay view must also redraw the polygons over the new map. So i do have to redraw everything. I like the OPENGL solution and will look further into it. Thanks.

Comment: I believe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394934/iphone-layering-a-transparent-opengl-view-on-top-of-a-uiview answers your question about using OpenGL ES on top of a UIView.