# How to display web page in background in Cocos2D?

Tags: ios, background, webview, cocos2d-iphone

I want to display a web page in the background of my game using Cocos2D in iOS.
I know CCUIViewWrapper, but it's not displaying in background.

Let me know the possible ways.

Comment: placing webview background? then what about front cocos2d view, Is it  transparent?

Comment: Yes, transparent with some images.

Answer (score 0):

See answer in thread: [Layering a transparent openGL view on top of a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394934/iphone-layering-a-transparent-opengl-view-on-top-of-a-uiview)

Apply same concept to Cocos2d OpenGL View in AppDelegate class.

```
CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8 //kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   //kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0    //GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];
```

Comment: I mean here you get glView and make it transparent...check that similar post...I didnt try but those post match your requirement.